# RESTful Web Service Inter-Methods communication

Tags: rest, callback

I have 2 web services (WSa) & (WSb)...

A web service (WSa) is going to call the method (Mx) of web service (WSb)...

A web service (WSb) is going to notify user (U1) to answer a certain question (Q1)...

User (U1) will reply to (WSb) by calling another method (My) and passing the answer...

Now, how can (WSb) replies to (WSa)'s original request?!

In other words, how can the method (Mx) wait for the user (U1) to call method (My) before it sends its reply back to service (WSa)?!

I tried to define a static boolean field (sem) within (WSb) that can work as a Semaphore. So after notifying the user for input, method (Mx) will loop as far as sem = true. When user (U1) calls method (My) and provides his/her answer, sem is set back to false so that method (Mx) can pursue the execution and reply back to service (WSa). However, the app crashes. I guess this is not the right way to deal with web services.

So what do you suggest having in mind that I can not alter service (WSa). I can only play with (WSb) and its RESTful methods?!

Please see the attached sequence diagram:
[image]

Comment: A [sequence diagram](https://bramp.github.io/js-sequence-diagrams/) would really help to clarify what's going on

Comment: @Devstr updated.

Comment: are you writing the service in Java? you can consider something like [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). Create a future in the WSb request thread, put it in some registry, and join on it. Then in other thread the user will provide an answer and complete the future, which will resume the request thread. I'll try to post a more elaborate answer later.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check it and get back to you. Yes I am writing WSb in JAVA.

Comment: I looked at some codes online, it does not seem to be working.
The semaphore solution looks fine, however, I do not know why it does not work?
If semaphore.acquire() is executed in Mx, method My is able to release it, however, I get the following error in WSa
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/html;charset=utf-8, type=class ...

Surprisingly the rest of the thread in Mx is not executed after it gets released!!!

Comment: Moreover, if I provide a random answer directly from Mx without waiting for the user to call My, it works!!! That means no actual issue with the method Mx declaration or the returned value, rather the issue is that Mx thread is not continuing the execution properly (for an unknown reason) after the semaphore is released by method My thread!!!
May be because it took long time to executed than what is expected by the framework?! If so, then how to set this timeout having in mind that the whole procedure (notify the user, & user reply by calling My) did not take more than 2 miniutes?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, handling asynchronous execution is better than making a thread wait for a code to get executed (its even worse incase of a user intervention).

You can generate unique id for each request from WSa and send a asynchronous callback from WSb along with id and response together after completion.